# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context with pdo wrapper class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using [simpleSQL - PDO](http://blog.csdn.net/btbdylq/article/details/6826225) class in my php application,
and using by this code:

```
$where['username']=$_POST['username'];
$where['password']=md5($_POST['password']);

$DB = new DB();
$res=$DB->buildQuery('tbl_admin',$where);
```

it is working fine in localhost, but in online server it get the error this:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in DB.php on line 230
```

line no. 230 in DB class is:

```
$ item  = $ this- > instance- > quote ($ this- > escape ($ item));
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: you 230 line is in a function in the actual class or is outside of the class?

Comment: yes it is in actual class, not outside. .check here [simpleSQL - PDO](http://blog.csdn.net/btbdylq/article/details/6826225)

Comment: check php version on localhost and server

Comment: localhost has version `PHP 5.3.5` and online server `PHP 5.2.17`

Comment: yes, in local with version 5.2.17 getting the same error. ..is there any solution?. ..because i can't change my server's version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the class.

In the `buildQuery` method:

```
array_walk($where,'DB::prepareDbValues');
```

This calls the `prepareDbValues` method statically (therefore, not in object context -> `$this` is not defined). To fix this issue, replace it by

```
array_walk($where,array($this, 'prepareDbValues'));
```

And report the bug and the fix to the class' author.